# joining dots of a scatter plot and create a line

Tags: maple

How is possible to join dots of a scatter plot after plotting, and make a line from a dotted plot?

Comment: Won't that make it just a regular plot ? In what way (as x increases ?) do you wish to join dots in such a plot ?

Comment: You have changed the tag from matlab to maple. Since there was no reference to what tool are you using we assumed it is matlab. I'd recommend to create new question with proper tagging, so you can get answer from maple experts faster. And be more specific for us not to make assumptions.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing you generated a scatter plot from `x` and `y` coordinates by,

```
plot(x,y,'.');
```

Join them with

```
plot(x,y,'.');
hold on;
plot(x,y,'-');
```

Or in one command

```
plot(x,y,'.-');
```

Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 3):

If you have an existing plot as a scatter plot, you cannot simply just join the dots without knowing which points are connected to which others.

If you know the order/connectivity of the points, then you could simply have used the plot function to do that in the first place. The call

```
plot(x,y,'-')
```

will connect the dots with straight line segments. If you wish to use a marker symbol at each point along the line, then you can add one of the markers that plot allows, as this:

```
plot(x,y,'o-')
```

You can get a list of the allowed markers from

```
help plot
```

If you have used scatter on a set of points, and now wish to overlay a line connecting the points, then use the hold function to force matlab to plot on top of the scatter plot. For example,

```
scatter(x,y)
hold on
plot(x,y,'-')
hold off
```

Again, any of these variations require you to know the connectivity between the points. There are some schemes that can sometimes work to recover that connectivity from a list of isolated points. One of these methods is called [CRUST](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~amenta/powercrust/algorithm.html), often used for 3-d surface reconstruction. I found many references by a simple search for "crust algorithm".

Answer (score 1):

If you have a scatterplot (made with the scatter function I suspect) and for some reason don't want to redraw it with plot, here is what you can do to connect the dots:

```
h = findobj(gca,'type','hggroup');
hold on
for k=1:numel(h)
    x = get(h(k),'xdata');
    y = get(h(k),'ydata');
    plot(x,y,'-')
end
hold off
```

The dots will be connected by their original order. If you want you can sort the data before plot, for example by x:

```
[x,ind] = sort(x);
y = y(ind);
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question of how to do this in Maple, you can simply use the [PointPlot](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Statistics/PointPlot) command from the [Statistics](http://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/features/statistics.aspx) package with the `style` option set to `line` or `pointline`. For example:

```
Statistics:-PointPlot([2, 4, 6, 4], xcoords=[1, 2, 3, 4], style=pointline);
```

Specifying the option `style` = `pointline` shows both the points and a connecting line; `style` = `line` shows just the line.